# Populating multicolumn ListView with txt file (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have a file named "music.txt" in directory res/raw. It contains a list of songs and authors separated by ";", like this:

Bohemian rhapsody;Queen

Piano man;Billy Joel

Born to run;Bruce Springsteen

And I want to use that list to populate a 2 column ListView. When I try to run with my current code it shows an error that says "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView". So far I've only been trying to get it working with just the first column, so help would be appreaciated to do it with the 2 columns as well because I have no idea how to do it.

I gave permission to read in manifest by the way. Here is my code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    list = findViewById(R.id.musicList);

    loadData();

}

public void loadData(){
    List<String> musicArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        if (is != null) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                musicArray.add(line.split(";")[0]);
            }
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String data[] = musicArray.toArray(new String[musicArray.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, data);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}


}
```

ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/musicList"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="729dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, data);
```

ArrayAdapter requires the **resource ID** to be a TextView